# Flutter: Dart Cast Error (Null check operator used on null value)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-future

I am new with Flutter, I am trying to open camera, for this I followed example code but when ever I debug my app it gives me Exception as shown in image [image: Error Image]

Here's my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'home.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<Null> main() async {
  try {
    cameras = await availableCameras();
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e.code\nError Message: $e.message');
  }
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'RealTime Detection',
      home: HomePage(cameras),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this:

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'RealTime Detection',
        home: FutureBuilder<List<CameraDescription>>(
          future: availableCameras(),
          builder: (
            BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<List<CameraDescription>> snapshot,
          ) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return HomePage(snapshot.data);
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: Shall I remove my try catch block from void?

Comment: yes, you don't need it anymore. you can handle it within `availableCameras()` method.